# SSRS Dynamic Hypherlink

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report that list different report names, but I wanted to add a dynamic hyperlink that when the report name is clicked that report will run. Note that the report name is not always the same, it changes daily. So far, I only know how to add an Action either Go To Report or Go To URL and this is on a single instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the report name in an expression for either the **Go To Report** or **Go To Url** Actions.

You can reference hard-coded values, or have the report name in a field in your data.

[image]

In this example, the **Report Name** field is used as the report to go to when the text is clicked.

You could also hard code the values and choose based on another condition using an IIF statement.

[image]
Then have an expression to inserst the desired report name into a string with the rest of your URL for the report server.

```
="http://sql01/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fDepartments%2fReporting%2f" & IIF(Fields!RECORD_TYPE.Value = 1, "Report1", "Report2")
```

How you do it would depend on where the logic is for choosing which report to show. Is your query going to return the report name or are you going to use other logic in the Go To Action to determine which report to go to?

Comment: I think i would have to create another field for the URL and populate that new field then use the go to url action.